Alpine Mail - use 2 smtp servers for my 2 email accounts
I have been using Alpine for a few days and have managed to retrieve my two email accounts @web.de and @gmx.de. They are displayed in the Folder List.
I can read and delete Mails etc. Fine.
But: How do I ensure that when writing an email, not only the gmx account is used for sending?
Where could I enter the second smtp server? So that I can choose even if I want to send from web or gmx.
I would appreciate it if someone has an answer.
Thank you very much.
Best regards,
Bacchus

I think there are several ways of solving this.
As far as I've gathered, Alpine allows to set role-specific SMTP servers. I do however not use this option myself and do not know of its implications.
However, a common solution is to install and configure msmtp, and then set sendmail-path in ~/.pinerc. One can of course set up a fuller smtp server, such as OpenSMTP, set up rule-based relaying there, and use that as an smtp server in Alpine. But this may be overkill for just solving this particular problem.
Thus, install msmtp, and edit ~/.msmtprc to configure it. An example template for a hotmail account and a gmail account is shown below.
defaults
auth            on
logfile         ~/.msmtp.log
timeout         120
tls             on
tls_starttls    on
tls_trust_file  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account         hotmail
host            smtp-mail.outlook.com
port            587
user            user.name@hotmail.com
password        some_password
from            user.name@hotmail.com

account         gmail
host            smtp.gmail.com
port            587
user            user.name@gmail.com
password        some_password
from            user.name@gmail.com

The "magic" is in the from commands, which instructs msmtp, when supplied with --read-envelope-from, to select the particular account based on the from-address of the email to be sent.
With passwords in clear text in the msmtp configuration file, this file must not be accessible by others that your user (permissions 0600). With more permissive access permissions, msmtp will refuse to work with the file.
When msmtp is installed and the configuration done, what remains is to set
sendmail-path=/usr/bin/msmtp --read-envelope-from --read-recipients

in your ~/.pinerc. This tells msmtp to select the outgoing smtp server based on the from-address and read the recepients from the email to be sent (otherwise you'd need to supply this explicitly, which wouldn't be suitable here).
Be sure to also unset smtp-server in your ~/.pinerc, as that setting overrides the usage of the sendmail program.
